# Cómo desplazarse a un elemento seleccionado en ListView

Tags: c++98

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en c++ Builder 6. Necesito desplazarme a un elemento seleccionado dentro de un ListView. Por ejemplo: si el ListView tiene 10 elementos en total y solo muestra 5 donde para ver los elementos restantes hay que hacer scroll. Si el 9no estuviese seleccionado como desplazaría el scroll automáticamente del ListView para que muestre el seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Get last item or any item you want
    TListItem *i = ListView1->Items->Item[ListView1->
                   Items->Count-1];

    // Calculate scroll amount
    int s = i->Top - ListView1->TopItem->Top;
    ListView1->Scroll(NULL, s);

    // Select last item
    i->Selected = true;

    ListView1->SetFocus();
}
```

Encontrada en este enlace: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.cppbuilder.vcl/OSSJKil8IrA